# How to set a default open page in TCPDF?

Tags: tcpdf

I'm generating a PDF with [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org). When a user opens the file, I'd like to open the PDF on page 3 instead of page 1.

I seem to recall this being possible in other PDF libraries, but I haven't been able to find anything in the API documentation for TCPDF.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, if file open in browser.
Use [`setDestination();`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a94cc2168d0b49e11f6c4d1420a6eb509) for create link:

```php
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->setDestination('chapter1', 0, '');
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, 'Chapter 1', 0, 1, 'L');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->setDestination('chapter2', 0, '');
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, 'Chapter 2', 0, 1, 'L');
```

And open file on selected page by link:
http://www.path.to/Your/file/name.pdf#chapter2

[Tcpdf example](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_015.phps);